# How to find givien index by name in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I know how to find index by name in MS SQL Server just by search for %name%

But where I can do the same in PGAdmin4 ?

Comment: `select * from pg_indexes where indexname like '%name%'`?

Comment: in MS SQL Management Studio I can search for them and easily delete by pressing DELETE button on the keyboard.

How I can delete them (indexes by %name% ) in PostgreSQL ?

Comment: No idea. I don't use pgAdmin.

Comment: pgadmn has none option for this use the sql comands

Answer (score 0):

As a horse_with_no_name provided, you can search the `pg_indexes` meta-table to find an index by name with the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pg_indexes 
WHERE indexname LIKE '%NameOfIndexYoureSearchingFor%';
```

Regarding your second question in the comments on how to delete an index in PostgreSQL, you can script it out with a query like this:

```
DROP INDEX NameOfIndexYouWantToDrop;
```

PostgreSQL documentation on [`DROP INDEX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropindex.html) for more information.